# Uncaught TypeError: _arc2.default.GreatCircle is not a constructor

Tags: leaflet, automatic-ref-counting, react-leaflet

Trying to create plugin for react-leaflet. I am getting this error while 
i am returning

> L.Polyline.Arc(position.from, position.to, option)

This is my Component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Path } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet'
import { Arc } from './leaflet.arc';


export default class ArcLine extends Path {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
      PropTypes.node,
    ]),
    option:PropTypes.object,
    position: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  createLeafletElement (props) {
    const { position, option, ...options } = props
    return L.Polyline.Arc(position.from, position.to, option)
  }

  updateLeafletElement (fromProps, toProps) {
    if (toProps.position !== fromProps.position) {
      this.leafletElement._createLatLngs(line, toProps.position.from)
    }
    this.setStyleIfChanged(fromProps, toProps)
  }
}
```

./leaflet.arc is

```
import arc from 'arc';
/**
 * Transform L.LatLng to {x, y} object
 * @param {L.LatLng} latlng
 * @returns {{x: {number}, y: {number}}}
 * @private
 */
const _latLngToXY = latlng => ({
    x: latlng.lng,
    y: latlng.lat
});

/**
 * Create array of L.LatLng objects from line produced by arc.js
 * @param {object} line
 * @param {L.LatLng} from
 * @private
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function _createLatLngs(line, from) {
    if (line.geometries[0] && line.geometries[0].coords[0]) {
        /**
         * stores how many times arc is broken over 180 longitude
         * @type {number}
         */
        let wrap = from.lng - line.geometries[0].coords[0][0] - 360;

        return line.geometries
            .map(subLine => {
                wrap += 360;
                return subLine.coords.map(point => L.latLng([point[1], point[0] + wrap]));
            })
            .reduce((all, latlngs) => all.concat(latlngs));
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

if (!L) {
    throw "Leaflet.js not included";
}  else if (!arc && !arc.GreatCircle) {
    throw "arc.js not included";
} else {
    L.Polyline.Arc = function (from, to, options) {
        from = L.latLng(from);
        to = L.latLng(to);
debugger

        var vertices = 10;
        var arcOptions = {};
        if (options) {
            if (options.offset) {
                arcOptions.offset = options.offset;
                delete options.offset;
            }
            if (options.vertices) {
                vertices = options.vertices;
                delete options.vertices;
            }
        }

        var generator = new arc.GreatCircle({x: from.lng, y: from.lat}, {x: to.lng, y: to.lat});

        var line = generator.Arc(vertices, arcOptions);
        var latLngs = [];

        var wrap = 0; // counts how many times arc is broken over 180 degree
        if (line.geometries[0] && line.geometries[0].coords[0])
            wrap = from.lng - line.geometries[0].coords[0][0];

        line.geometries.forEach(function(line) {
            line.coords.forEach(function (point) {
                latLngs.push(L.latLng(
                    [point[1], point[0] + wrap]
                ));
            });
            wrap += 360;
        });
        line.geometries[0].coords
        return L.polyline(latLngs, options);
    };
}
```

Why am i getting this error, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In this line here:

```
import { Arc } from './leaflet.arc'
```

...you are trying to import the Arc variable from your `leaflet.arc` file.  However, in your `leaflet.arc` file it doesn't look like you are exporting anything, simply attaching the Arc function to Leaflet's Polyline object.  Also, in the code in your component you are not even using the `Arc` variable that you are trying to import.  So, the code fails because a property is trying to be read from the undefined export from `leaflet.arc`.  It seems that you should probably just import the file without trying to import any objects.

TLDR:

Replace this line:

```
import { Arc } from './leaflet.arc'
```

with this:

```
import './leaflet.arc'
```

Comment: I tried this too but same error. Using debugger my code is working the data is passed as i can see but stop there when var generator = new arc.GreatCircle({x: from.lng, y: from.lat}, {x: to.lng, y: to.lat});

Comment: try changing this line: `}  else if (!arc && !arc.GreatCircle) {` to this: `}  else if (!arc || !arc.GreatCircle) {` in your leaflet.arc file.

Comment: It is saying Uncaught arc.js not included, and with console.log(arc) i get empty object. but i have included arc.

Comment: have you included arc in your package.json and installed it?

Comment: yes i used npm install --save arc, at packge json i have got dependency
"arc": "^0.1.0"

Comment: Weird.  Do you have your project on github or something where I could take a deeper look?

Comment: At the moment no, i just copied all arc.js and did import arc from './arc' for moment its ok. When i will upload it, i will give link.